# Suitable Replacement RIFA Capacitors for Apple IIE PSU

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, apple

I have an Apple IIE that I'm trying to bring back to life and in my research, everything suggests replacing the RIFA capacitors in the power supply. I'm looking for suitable replacement RIFA capacitors and wondered if anyone can tell me if I'm choosing suitable replacements? There are two RIFA capacitors in the Power Supply (Astec Components 250v) and they certainly look old and cracked (see photos below)

**0.1uf X RIFA Capacitor Details**
40/085/56 GPC C6 PME 271 M 610
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Capacitor-Class-0-1UF-Compatible-Capacitors/dp/B084MJV1PR/ref=sr_1_5?crid=1EOB1ST6IIWP3&keywords=riva+capacitor+x2&qid=1654447492&sprefix=rifa+capacitor+x%2Caps%2C74&sr=8-5

**0.47uf X RIFA Capacitor Details**
Can't quite make out the details without removing but I believe also X Class PME 271 M
Would this be a suitable replacement?
https://www.amazon.co.uk/EVOX-RIFA-CAPACITOR-0-047UF-FILTERS/dp/B09KV9D3TV/ref=sr_1_1?crid=35QD9GWONNU34&keywords=rifa+capacitor+0.47&qid=1654447365&sprefix=rifa+capacitor+0.47%2Caps%2C64&sr=8-1

I'm based in Ireland, I found similar components on sites such as rs-online.com, but they require buying 5 or more and I only need one of each. If anyone has any other suggestions of components sites or particular replacements I should look at it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: 0.47uf RIFA Capacitor]

[[image: 0.1uf RIFA Capacitor2]

[image: 0.47uf RIFA Capacitor]

Comment: DO NOT replace them with RIFA capacitors. There's a reason these always need to be replaced, and it's because RIFA capacitors tend to fail quite badly. Replace them with suitably rated film capacitors from a better brand like KEMET or TDK.

Comment: For purchasing in small quantities in Europe, I believe RS Components and Farnell/element14/Newark are the usual suggestions. I believe Mouser and Digikey also ship worldwide, but Mouser may have warehouses in Europe and I'm pretty sure Digikey doesn't.

Comment: So how do you know that changing these capacitors will help fixing the device? Sure, these may be old but unless the caps cause the fuse to blow up, the caps are not the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Hearth would this be suitable? https://www.mouser.ie/ProductDetail/KEMET/PMR209MC6100M470R30?qs=ffqAhwBssBuT2wbAk%2Fdv3w%3D%3D

Comment: @Justme the capacitors appear cracked and everywhere I read about repairing these computers talks about these going up in smoke when powering on after a long time sitting around. So just a preventative measure rather than a fix.

Comment: @Justme RIFA capacitors should always be replaced as a matter of course, they're notorious for failing violently.

Comment: @Hearth looking at the various options supplied by Mouser I'm struggling to choose the correct ESR. 22, 100, 220, 470 Ohms. Any advice? https://www.mouser.ie/c/passive-components/capacitors/film-capacitors/?q=100nf%20film%20capacitor%20x2

Comment: @LetsBooBoo ESR shouldn't matter, but those all sound *really* high. I notice you're using text search instead of parametric search in your link though, try using the parametric search. It works way better for finding things.